# How do I share a method between two classes?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone app that uses a Tab Bar Controller with 3 tabs.  Each tab is a separate class.  There are several methods that are identical in each class.  Instead of having three copies of the same method, I'd like to share the method between the classes.  However, I have not figured out how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classical case of inheritance.  Create a base class, and put all things that are common across the classes you are trying to build, into it, both functions and data members.  Then, derive your three classes for your tabs from this class (inherit from it, or make it the parent class, lots of overlapping terms here that people generally throw around).  Make sure your methods in the parent class are NOT defined as private methods.  That would make them inaccessible to your child classes.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Shouldn't the parent only have the common functionality? That would mean that you would have *three* subclasses: one first each tab. It seems very strange to use the "parent" as one of the three tabs. That would result in the other classes inheriting too much functionality.

Comment: As I said "Create a base class, and put all things that are common across the classes you are trying to build, into it, both functions and data members."  I forgot he was making three derived classes.  I never said to use the parent as one of the three tabs.  Sorry if my language was confusing to anyone!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure he didn't use the parent as a tab. What a mess that would be! Regardless, +1 to you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can make a new class and define that method inside that class which you want to share between more than one class.

Now whenever you want to access that method, just import the class and you can use the same method in multiple classes.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: To be more clear (perhaps), what AppAspect is saying is you should create a superclass with the base functionality you want each tab to have. For each tab you create a subclass as needed with all the required extra functionality specific to a tab. Check this site for an example (the Square class is a subclass of the Rectangle class): http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#subinheritance